# Cannot start Celery worker

Tags: python, celery

Trying to follow celery tutorial:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html

when i run

celery -A proj worker -l info

absolutely nothing happens in cmd console, no errors, no output. RabbitMQ is installed, service is running (windows 7, python 3.4.3)

How to fix?

Comment: Probably silly questions but you have duplicated the files and directory structure already and your calling the command from the directory above proj?

Comment: Please tell us what works on your system when you follow [first steps with celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps), then tell us what you already did to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a currently [an open bug issue with Celery in Windows 7](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/897) not showing results. Apparently it appeared after Celery 3.1.12 - perhaps you could downgrade until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Helped: according to discussion, the comment 
jennaliu commented on 30 Sep 2014  adding amqp  to app.conf is working: app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp'
),
 and now i see output. Because i am newbee i need further testing of tasks, maybe it is still dont work))

Answer (score 1):

I can not explain why but on windows it seems that using only one processor works :

```
celery -A proj worker -P solo -l debug
```